# Design issue : enhance code reusability specific case

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

Ive got a few instances of subclasses of View (like ImageView, ViewGroup, TextView, etc) , which i have them all implement two methods a() and b() and they all have to run the same init() method which is long and does the same for all of them. 
how should i design my architecture to enhance code reusability in that case?

if it was C++ i could multi inherite from view and a new abstract class that runs init() on time of creation and have abstarct methods a() and b(), how is it acheived in Java?

maybe there's some way to acheive it using some kind of a decorator?

Comment: I would create a separate "Globals" class and you can put methods in there that will be used by multiple activites and call them from the class that needs them. In each class when you need it just call 'Globals.a()'

Comment: Can't say I agree with that approach at all.

Comment: @codeMagic That's structural programming and it should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can create an abstract class `AbstractView` that extends `View` and implements your common `init()` method.  `AbstractView` should declare the abstract methods `a()` and `b()`, but leave the implementations to the subclasses.

```
public abstract class AbstractView extends View {
    public void init() {
        // common init implementation here
    }

    public abstract void a();
    public abstract void b();
}
```

Since you're trying to add behavior to a group of existing subclasses (`ImageView`, `ViewGroup`, `TextView`, etc.), you probably do need to create a wrapper for each subclass (`MyImageView`, `MyViewGroup`, `MyTextView`, etc.).  Each of these subclasses would extend `AbstractView` and implement their own `a()` and `b()` methods, but inherit the common `init()` method (along with all of the methods implemented in the `View` class.  You can then create delegate methods for the exising behavior in `ImageView`, `ViewGroup`, `TextView`, etc. that you need to keep unchanged.

```
public class MyImageView extends AbstractView {

    private ImageView wrappedImageView;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        wrappedImageView = new ImageView(context);
    }

    // TODO: Implement other constructor wrappers

    final void clearColorFilter() {
        wrappedImageView.clearColorFilter();
    }

    // TODO: Implement other method wrappers

    @Override
    public void a() {
        // specific implementation here
    }

    @Override
    public void b() {
        // specific implementation here
    }
}
```

Comment: Also `View` could be declared as an interface which defines the contract which all your views should be bound to.

Comment: @ArunManivannan That's a possibility, but Android already has a `View` class.  It's not clear if the OP is extending that, or starting from scratch.

Comment: Ouch. Didn't notice the "android" tag. Sorry about that.

Comment: @OfekRon Oh, I didn't realize ImageView, ViewGroup, TextView, etc. were also already built-in classes.

Comment: @OfekRon See my updates.  This is tricky (read "messy") because you're trying to add new behavior in between a super class and its subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new abstract class with the init() method:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractView extends View {
  public void init() {
    //TODO: implement init 
  }
  public abstract void a();
  public abstract void b();
}
```

Let your classes (ImageView, TextView) inherit from this abstract class.

Comment: they are not my classes, imageview etc are built in android, thats basiclly why i didnt go with this approach right away

Comment: @OfekRon If these classes are built-in, then how do you achieve: _i have them all implement two methods a() and b()_

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly undestood your answer, what you should do is the following:

```
public abstract class MyBaseView extends View{

  public MyBaseView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }


  private void init(){

  }

  public abstract void a();
  public abstract void b();
}
```

and then extend it again using:

```
public class MyView extends MyBaseView{

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void a() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void b() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class hierarchy which implement methods init() a() b(). Add content in steps with depending on the child class in the hierarchy. In the end your view will call methods on this class and generate content for itself.

```
      interface WidgetContent {
        void init();

        void a();

        void b();
    }

    abstract class AbstractWidgetContent implements WidgetContent  {
        public void init(){}

        public abstract void a();

        public abstract void b();
    }

    class BaseViewWidgetContent extends AbstractWidgetContent {

        public void a() {
        }

        public void b() {
        }

    }

    class ImageViewWidgetContent extends BaseViewWidgetContent {

        public void a() {
        }

        public void b() {
        }
    }

class PictureView extends ImageView{
    ImageViewWidgetContent imageContent;

}
```